# camera preview on lockscreen

Tags: android, camera, preview, lockscreen

I want add a take picture function in lockscreen , and I need to open the preview on screen , but it's fail all the time , logcat say the Error is about "setPreviewWindow - Null ANativeWindow passed to setPreviewWindow" and "startPreview - Preview not started. Preview in progress flag set"

In keyguard_screen_tab_unlock.xml after the digital clock view, put

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mPreview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In LockScreen.java constructor:

```
FrameLayout mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mPreview);
SurfacePreview preview = new SurfacePreview(mContext);
preview.setZOrderOnTop(true);
mFrameLayout.addView(preview);
```

SurfacePreview class :

```
public class SurfacePreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    SurfacePreview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
```

Anyone kown how to resolve this issue and start prview on LockScreen? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you get the answer?